# Should I change litter weekly even if it is hardly used?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, adoption, hygiene

In line with the n + 1 rule I planned to buy a third litter box. I inspect/scoop both my current boxes 1-2 times a day, and I hardly see any use of second one. It seems that it is a bit of waste to change litter if it was practically unused (they are sisters so I guess they are used to sharing) as I feel like I'm throwing away 2-3 inches of clean litter. For those 2 backup litter boxes, should I change the litter weekly?

I use Worlds Best Cat Litter if that matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a clumping litter, their usual advice is to sift-and-refill daily, and do a complete replacement monthly to get the bits that escape. I have never been certain about the necessity for that last, but it certainly won't hurt anything but your wallet.

In a rarely-used box, I'd say adjusting the replacement rate proportionately seems reasonable. But I Am Not A Vet.

Answer (score -1):

If litterbox #3 is barely used I wouldn't chuck it, though when you say barely used is it a few pees in a week?